# Why am I unable to write a CSS selector that finds a class wtihin an ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to write a CSS selector to take an element with a class but only if that class occurs within a particular ID.  I tried this

```
$("#contentArea .searchField").focus()
```

but its not finding it.  I don't get it because you can clearly see the element with the class "searchField" when I look at the HTML for only the ID itself (done through Google's dev console) ...

```
$("#contentArea").html()
"<form class="searchForm" action="/people/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Find person" data-autocomplete-source="/people/search" class="searchField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" class="btn-feedback" data-disable-with="Search">
</form>
"
$("#contentArea .searchField").html()
""
```

but notice above that nothing is selected when I try the actual selector.  How do I write my expression properly?

Comment: Shouldn't `$("#contentArea").html()` contain your form code?

Comment: Review your code, it seems you are putting the form HTML outside the `$("#contentArea").html()`.

Comment: #ContentArea is a DIV.  There's a form in that DIV.  Does that make sense?

Comment: searchField is an input, you cannot do `.html()` on it, if you want it's value, use `.val()`

Comment: Can we please get all the relevant HTML, including the #contentArea div?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working version of your code in [editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOGDZUTWWYPS).
It is the same as what you had used, and there shouldn't be any reason for it to not work unless there is some issue with your HTML or jQuery syntax. Snippet below will help you run it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contentArea .searchField").focus();
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="contentArea">
    <form class="searchForm" action="/people/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
      <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Find person" data-autocomplete-source="/people/search" class="searchField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" class="btn-feedback" data-disable-with="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Also, you are using .html() to fetch the value of the input, try using .val() instead if that was the original intent.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector works, it's your use of `.html()` that is wrong - as searchfield is an input, you cannot use that function on it.  If you want to find the value of the input, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
console.log($("#contentArea .searchField").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentArea">
  <form class="searchForm" action="/people/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Find person" data-autocomplete-source="/people/search" class="searchField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" value="testing">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" class="btn-feedback" data-disable-with="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```